# How do I copy a single element from an array to a vector in a specific location?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, vector, segmentation-fault

Been trying to get this to work for a while, but the error is either too vague or something urelated.
I am very new at coding so more complicated solutions may be too much for me.

```cpp
int main() {
    string NATOltr[27]{ ' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
    string NATOwrd[27]{ "-","alfa","bravo","charlie","delta","echo","foxtrot","golf","hotel","india","juliett","kilo","lima","mike","november","oscar","papa","quebec","romeo","sierra","tango","uniform","victor","whiskey","xray","yankee","zulu" };

    vector<string> input3xt{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' };
    vector<string> output3xt;
    for (int i = 0; i <= input3xt.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 26; j++) {
            if (input3xt[i] == NATOltr[j]) { (output3xt[i] = NATOwrd[j]) ;
            output3xt.push_back(i)
                std::cout << "_"; }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < output3xt.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << output3xt[i] << "\n";
    }

}
```

Usually the input vector or the loop number is not defined but I tried to isolate the problem. I am trying to make a NATO alphabet switcher, an online compiler just gives other errors, while visual studio sends me to this block of code:

```
    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 size_type size() const noexcept {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
        return static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst);
    }

    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 size_type max_size() const noexcept {
        return (_STD min)(
            static_cast<size_type>((numeric_limits<difference_type>::max)()), _Alty_traits::max_size(_Getal()));
    }

    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 size_type capacity() const noexcept {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
        return static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Myend - _My_data._Myfirst);
    }

    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    }

    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 const _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos) const noexcept /* strengthened */ {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    }

    _NODISCARD _CONSTEXPR20 _Ty& at(const size_type _Pos) {
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
        if (static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst) <= _Pos) {
            _Xrange();
        }
```

Edit: made a few changes a suggested, forgot I was originally working with a char vector, re-added it.
Edit 2: thank you [paulmckenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) and [thomas-matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews) for showing me that in the category of tables, if in doubt always use a different type.
now how do I close this?

Comment: What was the syntax error?  Because the snippet of code in your question does not appear to have a syntax error.  Also, don't post errors as pictures. Post them in text format.

Comment: `output3xt` is empty; you cannot subscript into it.  You need to add elements to the vector (using `push_back` or `resize` or similar).

Comment: What @MilesBudnek mentions means that `output3xt[i] = ...` can't be done. There are no elements in `output3xt` yet.

Comment: *so more complicated solutions may be too much for me.* -- From what I see, a `std::map<char, std::string>` would be far less code, and possibly much easier to understand.

Comment: In your `i` loop, you have a magic number `10`.  Why?  It's probably better to use `input3xt.size()`.  And even then it would only guarantee that `i` is an appropriate index into the `input3xt` vector.  It does not guarantee that `i` is an appropriate index for the `output3xt` vector, which is empty.  Accessing `output3xt[i]` doesn't add an element at the index `[i]`, if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: If your visual Studio install is right up to date  you can turn on the [Address Sanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170) to get much better fault diagnostics.

Comment: FYI [Here is what a map solution would look like](https://godbolt.org/z/edP78bEra).

Comment: You are writing a program that *associates* a *key* with a *value*.  The data structure is called *associative array*, *dictionary* and **map**.  You may want something like this:  `std::map<char, std::string> NATO_Dictionary = { {'a', "alpha"}, /*...*/};`

Comment: In this statement `output3xt.push_back(i)` you are pushing an int to a string vector????

Comment: `vector<string> input3xt{ 'h', 'e'...` This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= input3xt.size(); i++) ` is wrong.    Change the `<=` to `<`.    Valid indices for `input3xt` run from `0` to `intput3xt.size()-1`.      With the `<=`, the body accesses `input3xt[input3xt.size()]` which accesses an array element that does not exist and (often) causes a runtime error.   There is a similar problem with the loop over `j`.

Comment: We don't mark questions {SOLVED] by adding that to the topic. If you have an answer to your question, post it as such, and in appropriate  time accept it. Take the [tour] and read [help] to familiarize yourself with how the site works.

Comment: I advise reading [ask], in particular the part about introducing your question before posting any code. (Your excuses for why you could not solve this yourself can be omitted, or maybe moved to the bottom of the post if you really, really believe they will be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you are trying to use `[]` to index into a vector that has no elements.

> ```
> output3xt[i] = NATOwrd[j]
> ```

As noted in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) at cppreference.com, this invokes undefined behavior.

> Unlike std::map::operator[], this operator never inserts a new element into the container. Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.

Also, as per comments, you are better off using a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to model the mapping of character to string. If you do this, then this becomes a very straightforward application of [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::map<char, std::string> nato_map = {
      {' ', "-"}, {'a', "alpha"}, {'b', "bravo"}, {'c', "charlie"},
      {'d', "delta"}, {'e', "echo"}, {'f', "foxtrot"}, {'g', "golf"},
      {'h', "hotel"}, {'i', "india"}, {'j', "juliet"}, {'k', "kilo"},
      {'l', "lima"}, {'m', "mike"}, {'n', "november"}, {'o', "oscar"},
      {'p', "papa"}, {'q', "quebec"}, {'r', "romeo"}, {'s', "sierra"},
      {'t', "tango"}, {'u', "uniform"}, {'v', "victor"}, 
      {'w', "whiskey"}, {'x', "xray"}, {'y', "yankee"}, {'z', "zulu"}
    };

    std::string input = "hello world";
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    std::transform(
      input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
      std::back_inserter(output),
      [&](auto ch) { return nato_map[ch]; }
    );

    for (auto s : output) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hotel
echo
lima
lima
oscar
-
whiskey
oscar
romeo
lima
delta
```